# Bind radiobuttons to two different fields with Angular

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

need some help on radio buttons. How can i bind 2 radio buttons that are for one particular question but use 2 different fields in the database. For example there is a question that has a Yes/No answer. The yes answer binds to one field, and the No answer to another, they don't bind to a single filed that has a true, false value.

```
         <div class="radio-s">
            <input type="radio" ng-value="true" data-name="use_plan"
                   data-value="true" ng-model="record.offer_plan" />
            <label>Yes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio-s">
            <input type="radio" ng-value="false" data-name="use_plan"
                   data-value="true" ng-model="record.offer_plan" />                       
    <label>No</label>
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I feel like you are mixing different things here. The way your angular templates and controllers work has nothing to do with the data structure in your database

Comment: my question is, that how can i bind the same radiobutton list to different model values. As the example above, in a more correct situation the yes/no value would have been binded to one model value.

Answer (score 0):

Attach the name attribute to both of your radio buttons so that only one can be selected at a time and also bind them to the respective fields from your DB

```
        <div class="radio-s">
            <input type="radio" name="planGroup" ng-value="true" data-name="use_plan"
                   data-value="true" ng-model="record.offer_plan_yes" />
            <label>Yes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio-s">
            <input type="radio" name="planGroup" ng-value="false" data-name="use_plan"
                   data-value="true" ng-model="record.offer_plan_no" />                       
        <label>No</label>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt work. It isnt updating the model at all.